# How to handle multiple connection objects in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, network-programming, client-server

I am trying to implement client/server connection where server accepts multiple connections from the client. Now server is accepting multiple connections from the client but I have to do multiple connections simultaneously and have to keep established connections in waiting state.

the way I have implemented is as follows :

```
std::async ([=] { serverConnect(102, "127.0.0.1"); } );
std::async ([=] { serverConnect(102, "127.0.0.1"); } );
```

```
int serverConnect(int tcpPort, const string& hostname) {
    con = Connection_create();
    Connection_connect(con, hostname.c_str(), tcpPort);
    return con;
}
```

the above lines created two client connections simultaneously and returns connection object as shown above.

Now I have to make the connections to be in waiting state in order to do further operations.

I tried doing like below but that is not working for the next connection

```
int serverConnect(int tcpPort, const string& hostname) {
    con = Connection_create();
    Connection_connect(con, hostname.c_str(), tcpPort);
    while(con) {
    cout << "In waiting State" << endl;
}
}
```

The problem in the above is it works only for one connection and does not executes next thread though while loop wont fail until server disconnects.

I have to establish two connections and after establishment have to hold both the connections in waiting state.

Help me, How to implement ?

Comment: What do you mean by waiting state? You are not doing anything with the connection in the while loop. There's not supposed to be infinite loops with asynchronous I/O, the whole point of it is to do other things while waiting for something. Though in this case I'm not sure what you're trying to wait for?

Comment: I guess the gist of my question is, what are you trying to accomplish with the while loop, if it doesn't touch con at all? What's the difference between that and just returning?

Comment: forget about that while loop. what i have to do is i have to maintain the connection thread objects. when async called, it creates a thread and makes the connection and next thread will be created simultaneously. Once all my connections established now i have to manage all the threads.  Making it clear two threads are there and i have to do something with first thread. how to achieve it ?

Comment: Ok. So in each thread, you're establishing a connection, then waiting for all the other threads to finish establishing connections, so you can move on? Did I get that right?

Comment: yeah you r right. each thread establishes connection and after establishment i have to make all the thread in idle state instead getting destroyed.

Comment: in above case, thread getting destroyed which actually closes my connection that should not happen. I have to make all threads in idle state so all my connections are opened till i make a call to close it.

Comment: If you want it sequential why are you using asynchronous I/O? And threads?

Comment: It doesn't seem like they want it sequential. I think they want the connections to be handled in parallel, but at certain points want all the threads to reach a certain checkpoint before moving on.

Comment: @user207421 connections has to go parallel once all the connections are successful and after that i have to make threads idle (instead of closing) in order to do some other stuffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an std::promise for each thread. Call get_future() on each promise to get the associated std::future object. Store these futures in a global vector accessible to all threads, say asyncfutures. Then in each thread, call set_value on the std::promise for that thread after connection is created, and instead of the while loop, do:

```
for (auto fut : asyncfutures) {
    fut.wait();
}
```

then continue on with the thread activities.

What the wait() function does is wait for the other thread to call set_value on its promise. Once waiting for all other threads to call set_value (which happens after they establish a connection) finishes, then the for loop finishes, and all the threads together go on to use the connection.

If you want all the threads to wait not just for each other but also for some event in the main thread, you can add another future to async_futures and call set_value on the promise object once the event is reached.

No thread ever returns in this stage, so the connection object is not destroyed.

Note that std::promise is a template. You can look up more about promises and futures on cppreference.com .

EDIT: C++20 has added the `latch` type to the ISO C++ standard library. This allows you to construct a latch with its counter initialized at the number of threads about to run, and have each thread call `arrive_and_wait` on it when the thread arrives at the synchronization point. This will block the thread until the other threads have also arrived at the synchronization point.

As of April 23, 2020, support for C++20 is generally lacking or piecemeal among compilers, but it should catch up within the next year or two.